# Code is not working properly in mozila firefox

Tags: jquery

Account Code is not displaying correctly in input "type=number" in mozila firefox.it is working properly in chrome. this is only happening when code is getting greater than or equal to 17 digits.

Your Answer will be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Make an effort to solve the problem. If you run into a specific issue doing so, post a question with your attempt (the JavaScript code using jQuery), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far.

Comment: Could you show us what you have been done so far??

Comment: Define "Not working properly".  Also, this is clearly a client-side issue and therefore nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: @Pramod Patil I have used substr functions of php to get last 4 digits and increment  + 1 in it and then show in html thorough jquery

Comment: @GordonM I mean code is not displaying according to need you can se in developer tool json is returning correct code "new_ID" it should be shown in text box but it is adding 0000 to last 4 digits instead of 0002 This is displaying properly in Chrome but doing problem in mozila firefox

Comment: Come on, people. The original unedited post had all information needed to spot the problem immediately. Don't just go and downvote any post of a new member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your numbers are just too big for `<input type="number">`. Quoting a Mozilla developer from [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1161006):

> Your values exceed the maximum 53-bits that can safely be represented
>   as an integer in a IEEE 754 double-precision floating-point. Max value
>   before rounding is 9007199254740991. This is expected behavior.

So it looks like you won't be able to use `<input type="number">`. If you want to limit the allowed characters to digits in a normal text input, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input) might help.

**Edit:** The discussion in [this other, active bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1005603) might indicate that FF will at one point change its mind and use the original string value - not the converted number - for presentation, like I suppose Chrome does.